# Look up поля в sql+studio 2015(поле подстановки)

Tags: c#, sql, sql-server

Как реализовать look up в решении SQL Server 2014 + Visual Studio 2015?

Когда в VS2015 в конструкторе вытаскиваю поле из другой таблицы, то не создаются методы `insert`, `update`!

Когда пишу вручную метод `update` и метод `Insert`, он не может обновить и добавлять данные в это поле, так как оно из другой таблицы. Код этих методов в VS2015

Метод `insert`.

```
string sqlQ = "INSERT INTO Klient ( Fio,  ID_TS, NumberTS,   Number_Tel, Naimenovanie_TS) VALUES (@param1, @param2, @param3,@param4,@param5)";

using (SqlCommand comand = new SqlCommand(sqlQ, db))
{
    Form2 F = new Form2();

    comand.Parameters.AddWithValue("@param1", textBox1.Text);
    comand.Parameters.AddWithValue("@param2", comboBox1.Text);
    comand.Parameters.AddWithValue("@param3", textBox2.Text);
    comand.Parameters.AddWithValue("@param4",comboBox2.Text);
    comand.Parameters.AddWithValue("@param5", textBox3.Text);


    try { comand.ExecuteNonQuery();
        F = (Form2)this.Owner;
        F.button4_Click(sender, e);  Close();
    }
    catch
    {
    }
```

Сразу после запуска ругается на поле 'Naimenovanie_TS', что оно отсутствует.

Comment: Добавьте для ясности в вопрос код, который Вы пишете и поясните что именно у Вас не получается.

Comment: Столько поправок не одного ответа)) разобрался, кому будет интересно пишите